# Is there any non-obvious difference between using C++ or C# for a Windows Kinect application? (e.g. performance, features)

Tags: c#, c++, windows, kinect

Is it just a matter of preference and familiarity or the language makes an actual difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are treated as first-class supported languages in terms of the Kinect SDKs, but the C# version is I think just a wrapper around the C++ version.

Standard managed C# vs unmanaged C++ arguments apply from this point forwards.

My preference? I know C# very well and am comfortable using it, so I'd start with that. If I identify performance issues because I used C# I can tackle those later on, but I seriously doubt that would ever happen.

Don't forget, you could always dip into unsafe C# in order to improve performance on any image processing logic you have - and still keep the managed support.