# What language for Kinect?

Tags: programming-languages, kinect

I'm reading lots of different things and it seems perhaps more and more ports are coming out every day but what is the simplest (non ported) language to use to develop for XBox Kinect?

I've read C#, C++ and Java. I'm currently learning Processing and Paperscript as OpenFrameworks was a bit too difficult for my current level and outdated XCode (I couldn't follow the guide because of differences in interface). As a result though I am thinking of taking a course at the community college in either C++ or Java and am not sure which one would be a better lead up to doing things with the Kinect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++, C# and VB.NET are all supported with the Kinect SDK. I'm not certain, but I think the managed libraries are just wrappers around the unmanaged stuff - high quality wrappers I'm sure.

Note that these wrappers aren't "ports" in the hacked sense, they are fully supported APIs giving C# and VB.NET first class access into the Kinect SDK.

Something similar has also been asked here:

[Is there any non-obvious difference between using C++ or C# for a Windows Kinect application? (e.g. performance, features)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532936/is-there-any-non-obvious-difference-between-using-c-or-c-sharp-for-a-windows-k)

My personal preference is C#, because I know it better than C++. Trying to be objective here, I also think C# is "simpler" (as you put) to use as opposed to C++. In the end though, using Kinect itself can be complex depending on the maths you start getting into.

If this is going on the Xbox, Java won't be an option. Not sure about trying to use Java with the Kinect for Windows SDK, but personally I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 2):

I would totally recomment using `C#`. It is a lot easier than using `C++`. The .Net SDK makes it really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Ive tried using both c# and c++ and it sounds like your about as experienced as i am, and i liked c# MUCH more with my first project with kinect and now i hardly ever use c++, case in point: i would go with c#